# PC out of valid memory range

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to write an ARM Assembly program that opens and reads integers from a file. I am extremely new to ARM and do not think I fully understand whats going on here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 @ ========= Open file for reading =============================
 ldr r0,=inputFile        
 mov r1,#0       
 swi 0x6c          @ open file
 bcs InFileError       @ if cannot open file branch to InFileError 
 ldr r1,=InputFileHandle
 str r0,[r1]

 inputFile: .asciz "integers.dat"
 InputFileHandle: .word 0

 InFileError:
 ldr r1, =FileOpenErrorMsg
 swi 0x02 @ display error
 bal Exit

 FileOpenErrorMsg: .asciz "Error opening file."

 Exit:
 swi 0x68   @ close file
```

This is what I get when I try to run in ARMSim#:

```
PC Out of valid memory range, address 00011400

R0 :4140
R1 :4172
... (all 0)
R8 :37484
...
R13 :21504
R15 :70656
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing an `swi 0x11` (`SWI_Exit`)

Comment: Your data, inputFile and InputFileHandle, is interspersed with you code. Your code will fall through into it and attempt to execute it. Also it's probably not writable.

Comment: @Michael that fixed the PC out of valid memory range error, thanks! however, it seems as though most of the rest of it never gets executed

Comment: @RossRidge im a little confused, would you mind elaborating on that a little bit?

Comment: The bytes that make up the string `integers.dat` exist in memory right after the bytes that make up the instruction `str r0,[r1]`. After the CPU is done executing that instruction, it executes the instruction stored in memory immediately following it. The string `integers.dat` is what follows the instruction so the CPU executes that. However since code is normally stored in read-only memory, the `str r0,[r1]` instruction may fail before then.

Comment: Look at the memory view compared to the disassembly up top; see all those bytes mixed in with the recognisable instruction words? What do you think would happen after executing the `str r0, [r1]` instruction at 0x1014, and the PC increments to 0x1018? The reason that doesn't actually happen is because the code itself is wrong - according to the manual 0x6c is not the "open file" call, hence you always go down the failure path.

Comment: @RossRidge thanks it's starting to make more sense, is that why i always get 0 instructions executed?

Comment: @Notlikethat thanks for pointing that out, i misread the manual it should have been 0x66